# PHP Internal Server error on Nginx replacewildcardsinredirecturl()

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ioncube

I was installing a script that require ionCube loaders on a Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP5.6 and Nginx. ionCube Loaders appear to be working according to phpinfo page.

```
http://tutt2.com/phpinfo.php
```

Although majority of pages are working, I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error on page which is supposed to redirect to a third party page. This is the page that is giving the error.

```
http://tutt2.com/base.php?c=7&key=c98f46504d315fb435212cc15093d045&test=true
```

As you can see it's not redirecting. And this is what I see on NGINX error log.

```
2017/08/26 04:45:26 [error] 16801#16801: *767 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function replacewildcardsinredirecturl() in /home/tutt2/public_html/basecode.php on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 113.59.210.222, server: tutt2.com, request: "GET /base.php?c=7&key=c98f46504d315fb435212cc15093d045&test=true HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/php-nginx/15023718282643.sock/socket:", host: "tutt2.com", referrer: "http://tutt2.com/direct-and-landing-campaign.php?id=7"
```

I'm not sure what replacewildcardsinredirecturl() is. I've looked in basecode.php but it doesn't help since it's encrypted. Hope someone can point me to right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you are using a newer version of ionCube which is not supported on your PHP version? Or if you really want to see what the function gets, create in your code `function replacewildcardsinredirecturl($url){ var_dump($url); }` and see what it gets and if you don't get a fix, simulate the function yourself

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, it might have something to do with IonCube version. But I can't seem to find the previous versions. Only version they allow to download is IonCube Loaders v10. Do you know where to download IonCube v6.x ot even v5.x?

Comment: No idea, why don't you ask their support directly